# What is meant by $C^{k,a}$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Will somebody please explain to me what is meant by the notation $C^{k,a}$ ? It is similar to $C^k$ in the sense that it classifies some property of a function (ex. $C^2$ ==> twice continuously differentiable), in my case a curve.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It is a  [Hölder space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition). From Wikipedia:

> The Hölder space $C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open subset of some Euclidean space and $k \geq 0$ an integer, consists of those functions on $\Omega$ having continuous derivatives up to order $k$ and such that the $k$th partial derivatives are Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$, where $0 < \alpha\leq 1$.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain how I should improve this answer?